# Can I somehow simplify the perimetre of a rounded segment?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

I set myself a challenge of calculating the perimetre of a rounded segment (that is, a segment with the 'sharp' edges rounded off).

Here is a rough explanatory diagram:

[image: diagram showing a large circle, of radius R, and a chord a distance 'd' away from the origin of the circle. Two smaller circles, of radius r, rest tangential to the chord, that is they are wholly inside the segment. Equations on the diagram are transcribed below the next image]

And with the perimetre shown in red.

[image: a copy of the above image with the perimetre in red, and the three parts shown in green.]

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{d + r}{R-r}\right)$$
$$A=R\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)$$
$$B=r\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta\right)$$
$$C=(R-r)\times\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)\right)$$
$$P=2(A+B+C)$$

This looks correct to me, but I can't figure a good way to check that.

If this is correct, is there a clever way to simplify this? I feel like there must be a trigonometric identity I can leverage somehow. Otherwise expanding out P to include only d, r and R would look horrible.

Edit: here is a clearer diagram without my potentially wrong labeling:

[image: two diagrams showing large circle sections, each with two smaller circles on either side of the section so that they rest tangential to the curve of the section. Construction lines so various internal angles of one of the smaller circles]

Comment: If my question needs more clarity, could someone point out what needs clarifying please.

Comment: You could have added the perimeter in a different color. Also, it seems like $T$ is $\theta$. Or am I wrong about that? Also, it's not clear what are the known quantities

Comment: Where is the line segment you round ?

Comment: @andrei that would have been a good idea! And yes, I swapped letters mid way, but I can swap back.

Comment: @JeanMarie I uploaded a second image with the perimetre shown in red

Comment: Your answer for $C$ is wrong. $C=(R-r)\sin(\pi/2-\theta)$ will work. Btw, you have swapped $\theta$ and $\theta'$ in the image. Also I don't think this can be simplified to a nice form. PS: Also work with radians, not degrees (especially for $A$ and $B$).

Comment: @ACB Ahhh your right I swapped the two versions of *ϴ*. I can fix that, but I can't see how to get your result for *C*...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YBg9.png

Comment: @ACB ahhhh of course and now I feel dumb.  I edited this in, so I can focus on whether (or, like you said, not) this can be simplified.

Comment: @ACB I think you can rearrange $\theta$ to be in terms of $R-r$, and substitute that into C, to get $\sin(X)\times\sin(y)$ and eliminate one as a constant $\sin(\pi/2)$... Helpful?